# Can't paste images into Word copied from IE9

Tags: html, image

In IE9, right click an image, and copy it into clipboard, then go to Word, when I try to past it, Word asks me username and password.

Instead, copy and paste a SVG from IE to Word is OK.

Anybody knows why? and how to past it without username and password?

Answer (score 1):

Can you right click and select "save image as." Then in word you can insert that image.

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but it is not very convenient for customers.

Answer (score 0):

Right click > 'View image' > 'Save as' > Open word > Insert image > Browse your image > Enter

or

Right click > 'Copy image URL' > paste it in your address bar > Enter > Right click > 'Save as' > Open word > Insert image > Browse your image > Enter